# Track a branch in a bare git-svn

Tags: git, git-svn, git-bare

When I run this command:

```
git --git-dir=firebird.git branch -a
```

This is my output:

```
  B1_5_Release
  B2_0_Release
  B2_1_Release
  B2_5_Release
* master
  remotes/B1_5_Release
  remotes/B2_0_Release
  remotes/B2_1_Release
  remotes/B2_5_Release
  remotes/B3_0_Release
  remotes/origin/B1_5_Release
  remotes/origin/B2_0_Release
  remotes/origin/B2_1_Release
  remotes/origin/B2_5_Release
  remotes/trunk
```

A `B3_0_Release` branch was created in Subversion after this git-svn tree was setup. I don't have a `B3_0_Release` tracking `remotes/B3_0_Release`, or something like this. This is a bare repository, so I can't do a "git checkout -b ...".

How can I add this new branch to this bare repository?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way to create a branch in a git repository is `git branch <branch_name> [<where to branch at>]`, which would work for bare repositories as well, in your case

```
git --git-dir=firebird.git branch B3_0_Release remotes/B3_0_Release
```

Beware it won't be updated automatically upon changes at the svn upstream (neither the other local branches probably).

Comment: Worked, but now I do "git --git-dir=firebird.git push -u origin remotes/B3_0_Release:B3_0_Release" like I was doing for the others branches and it says: error: unable to push to unqualified destination: B3_0_Release
The destination refspec neither matches an existing ref on the remote nor
begins with refs/, and we are unable to guess a prefix based on the source ref.

Comment: That's a completely different question which is easy to google/stackoverflow. You don't even have to create a local branch if all you want is to push to remotes, simply do `git push origin remotes/B3_0_Release:refs/heads/B3_0_Release`